# How to create a relations in models with mutation method in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, graphql, prisma

I am creating an ecommerce api using GraphQL. My prisma schema is

```
model Product {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  name        String
  price       Int
  stocks      Int      

}

model User {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  email    String @unique
  password String
  Orders   Order[]
}


model Order{

  id     Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId Int
  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int
  @@unique([productId, userId])
}
```

What should be my graphql schema and resolver function in order to create a relation whenever a user orders a product?

Answer (score 3):

Your schema should actually look like this:

```
model Product {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  price     Int
  stocks    Int
  orders    Order[]
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model User {
  id       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String
  email    String  @unique
  password String
  orders   Order[]
}

model Order {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId Int
  user      User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
  @@unique([productId, userId])
}
```

And your GraphQL mutation should contain the user id and product id being passed as variables and your resolver would look like this:

```
  await prisma.user.update({
    where: {
      id: 1,
    },
    data: {
      orders: {
        create: {
          product: {
            connect: {
              id: 123,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

This will create a new order to the user id *1* and will add product id *123* to the order.